# Unable to use variable in constructing $pop query in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to use $pop on an embedded array in Meteor and I'm pretty certain that my limited understanding of variable scope and order of operations is causing me issues.

To provide a simplified example, this works:

```
do_thing = function(foo) {
  Coll.update(foo, {$pop: { "bar.baz": 1 }} );
};

do_thing( "123" );
```

But this does not:

```
do_thing = function(foo, bar) {
  var tmp = bar + ".baz"
  Coll.update(foo, {$pop: { tmp: 1 }} );
};

do_thing( "123", "bar" );
```

The core issue is that the update succeeds when I hard-code the array from which I wish to pop the item, but the update fails when that array is dynamically constructed.  I assume the cause is *not* the fact that it is a variable since 'foo' works, and instead the problem lies in the way that 'tmp' might not be getting instantiated in time for the update() call.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve the result I'm looking for: popping an item from a field whose name I won't necessarily know until I'm in the function?

Alternately, I'm open to broader suggestions of how to construct this function if I'm taking a completely wrong-headed approach in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal string "tmp" is being used for the key name, rather than the value you are passing in for the variable "tmp".

Try this:

```
updateboj = {}
updateobj[tmp] = 1
Coll.update(foo, {$pop: updateobj} );
```